# Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error:Unrecognized token '<'

Tags: php, mysql, database, react-native, react-native-ios

I am quite new in React Native.
I have Login and Register pages which work well.
After the user has logged in, the profile page should render Welcome + his name.
I wrote a frontend and backend codes, but something doesn't work well.

Profile.js

```
export default class Profil extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={name:''}
};

componentWillMount(){
  return this.getUser();
}

getUser(){
  return fetch('https://lifestormweb.000webhostapp.com/profile.php',{
  method:'GET',
  headers:{
          'Accept':'application/json',
          'Content-Type':'application/json',
      }
  })
  .then((response)=>response.json())
  .then((response) => this.setState({
  name: response.name})
  )
  }

  render() {
return (
  <View>
    <Header
      centerComponent={{ text: 'Profil', style: { color: '#FF0000', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' } }}
      outerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}
    />
    <Text>Willkommen {this.state.name}</Text>
  </View>
);
}
```

profile.php

```
<?php
$dbservername = "id6354774_users";
$dbusername = "id6354774_root";
$dbpassword = "*********";
$dbname = "localhost";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$post_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM UserRegistrationTable WHERE name='$post_name'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Your PHP code retrieves data and then outputs...nothing. Presumably you want to dump out some JSON data with `json_encode`?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.